# how to delete library file permanently on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I try to use the new api of Windows Phone 8.1 .
I heard i can remove Library file from application. But when i try to use the function "StorageFile.DeleteAsync" , i just see the file removed from the localStorage and no from the music Library ( the true storage).

Can i really delete a file from the Library with Windows phone 8.1 O.S ?

I just want know how implemant it. I know it's possible , they have a lot of application how allow manage file (read,write) like "Aerize Explorer" for example

This is the code i use:

```
    #region Main
    public Main()
    {
        Task.Run(async () => Global.Explorer.DeleteMusicFile(await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync("title.mp3")));
    }
    #endregion

    public class FileExplorer
    {
        // DeleteFile
        public async Task DeleteMusicFile(StorageFile fileToDelete)
        {
            await fileToDelete.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just an assumption but i'd say this may be working as intended? Would you really want random apps to mess with files on your file system? Sounds potentially dangerous to me. Considering it's StorageFile already points out you're working with a file in the storage rather than just a normal file.

Comment: Hi , i'm not sure to understand everything . Sorry for my bad english. You said , it's can be dangerous if i allow the users to delete music files from my app ? I just want know how implemant it. I know it's possible , they have a lot of application how allow manage file (read,write) like "Aerize Explorer" app for example

Comment: I see. That's interesting. I'd expect an app to require advanced permissions to access files outside of its sandbox. In that case you can ignore my comment.

Comment: Yes it's intersting , that why i try to implemant this feature by myself but not documentation found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Can i really delete a file from the Library with Windows phone 8.1 O.S ?

Yes, you can - [here is an example of an App](http://1drv.ms/1oXJCL2) (WP8.1 Runtime) which does it - whach out when testing - it deletes the file pernamently, without prompting ;). It mostly consists of lines:

```
var listBefore = (await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync()).ToList();
await listBefore.FirstOrDefault().DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
var listAfter = (await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync()).ToList();
```

I get the list of *StorageFiles*, then I delete the first of them. As a result, the second time I get the list of files - it's lack one file (the deleted one). So it works.

Remember to add *Capabilities*: *MusicLibrary* and/or *Removable Storage*. And watch out if the file you want to delete is not used elsewhere.

As I've spotted that I'm not able to refresh the files which are on the phone in Explorer Window (browsing it in Windows via USB). To see the result (file missing), I had to unplug and plug the phone again.

Comment: Yess thank's a lot ! I just see now , the problem is the Explorer Windows can not refresh the result. need unplug and plug the phone again :-) . I mark this as an answer